# How to upload a file using httppost FileEntity working with PHP server

Tags: java, php

My java code on the client is：

```
FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(zipfile, contentType);
post.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

I want to receive it  using PHP on apache server. 
I have no idea how to set the first value in `$_FILES[" "]["tmp_name"]` in the php function `move_uploaded_file($_FILES[" "]["tmp_name"],$upload_file)`.
I have seen others asked the same question.but the answer is not clearly enough. I am waiting for your answer,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm ready with my own test and it's been done on android by downloading apache httpclient, but that should'nt be a problem for your case.

I included httpclient.jar and httpmime.jar in 'libs'-folder.

The most important thing is to set the part-name on the mime-part of the multipart-message. That is the first part of your assoc. php array.

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_string);
        File file = new File(file_string);

        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
        mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);

        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out
                .println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        System.out.println(statusLine);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
        if (resEntity != null) {
            resEntity.consumeContent();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        return statusLine != null ? statusLine.getStatusCode() : 0;
```